# How do I stop getting this ReferenceError in node.js?

Tags: javascript, templates, node.js, ejs

```
    183|             });
    184| 
 >> 185|             <% if(just_registered) { %>
    186|                 alert("Welcome!");
    187|             <% } %>
    188| 

just_registered is not defined
```

Basically, I want to say: if just_registered is defined and is true, then alert. However, I want want to set everything to false...I just want to leave it undefined (i have like 100 variables)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`<% if(typeof just_registered !== "undefined") { %>`

Basically your checking whether a local variable exists. To do this you have to use the `typeof` operator since accessing `just_registered` which is an undeclared local variable creates a reference error.

This is best compared to

```
var foo;
if (foo) { }
```

vs

```
//var foo;
if (foo) { } // ReferenceError
```

Where as

```
//var foo
if (typeof foo !== "undefined") { }
```

Will work because accessing an undeclared variable with the typeof operator just returns `"undefined"` rather then throwing a `ReferenceError`