# How do I make JST parameter be optional?

Tags: javascript, ejs

How do I make [JST](http://embeddedjs.com/) parameter be optional without doing

```
<%= typeof defVal !== 'undefined' ? defVal : '' %>
```

thanx.

Comment: There's not a great way to do this since the variable actually doesn't exist _and_ it's not defined. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645512/how-do-i-stop-getting-this-referenceerror-in-node-js?rq=1).

Comment: Reason i'm devastated is because it's just javascript. And in javascript you can do defVal || "actual value" wright?

Comment: That only works if `defVal` actually exists, and if `defVal` was null or undefined, it would work. I've done something similar where I would define `defVal = null;` on the compound server just so the ejs script doesn't require the `typeof` stuff.